# Unable to check if user is a member of distribution list using Powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to add a user to Distribution group using Power Shell. But  i want to check if user is already a member of the Distribution List and if he is the member of the Distribution List  i want to store the result in a variable so that i can make further decision. So far i have tried the below script but it gives the list of all the member. Please help me with this.

```
$dl=Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity DL_Name
```

if i can store a result in some variable then further logic can be made.

Comment: You can either check if the user is member of this DL by querying the DL or you query the user and check if the DL is in the memberOf attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please share the script to query the DL. It will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and the code you are currently using provides you with a list of all members then all you need to do is check to see if that list contains the member you want to add before adding.

```
if ($dl -notcontains $userToAdd) {
  Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity DL_Name -Member $userToAdd
}
```